# How to add custom site installer to plesk?

Tags: plesk

I have my custom framework and I want to create lots of website with my framework.
I use Plesk to manage my host , so I want to know if we can create a custom site installer like Plesk built in feature for Wordpress.
I want to give my customer this feature to create their website themselves.
And also I want that if I upgrade my framework , copy new files to my customers website without notice them. so because there is lots of website I cant copy to their website one by one , I want if there is a way to copy file from a source to them with Plesk ?

Answer (score 1):

Plesk uses APS standard to pack web applications.

You can create your own APS package(it's a zip archive created by standard rules with meta description) like for WordPress package https://dev.apsstandard.org/apps/1.2/wordpress.org/WordPress/Plesk/

Pay attention that Plesk doesn't support APS 2.0 and not all features of APS 1.2

When you create you own package you can upload it in Plesk > Tools&Settings > Application and it become available for installation on sites.

Pay attention that WordPress APS package and WordPress Toolkit - it's a two different technologies. Toolkit just uses APS package for WordPress installation and basic configuration.